# Exceeded the number of columns that can be updated simultaneously

Tags: c#, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

I'm trying to load data to the Amazon Keyspaces Managed Cassandra. It's working fine for some of the simple objects but when I tried to load a table with 286 columns im getting the error

> Exceeded the number of columns that can be updated simultaneously

Can someone help?

Below is my code

```
var batch = mapper.CreateBatch(BatchType.Unlogged)
                    .WithOptions((options) => options
                    .SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LocalQuorum));
                lines.ForEach((item) =>
                {
                    batch.Insert(item);
                });
                mapper.Execute(batch);
```

And my schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS congaplatformpoc.cpq_li (
  Id uuid,
  QuoteId uuid,
  Name text,
  CreatedById uuid,
  CreatedOn timestamp,
  ModifiedById uuid,
  ModifiedOn timestamp,
  OwnerId uuid,
  AdHocGroupId text,
  AddedByRuleInfo text,
  AddedBy text,
  AdjustedPrice text,
  AdjustmentAmount text,
  AdjustmentType text,
  AllocateGroupAdjustment int,
  AllowManualAdjustment int,
  AllowProration int,
  AllowRemoval int,
  AllowableAction text,
  AssetId text,
  AssetLineItemId text,
  AssetQuantity text,
  AttributeValueId text,
  AutoRenew int,
  AutoRenewalTerm text,
  AutoRenewalType text,
  BaseCostOverride text,
  BaseCost text,
  BaseExtendedCost text,
  BaseExtendedPrice text,
  BasePriceMethod text,
  BasePriceOverride text,
  BasePrice text,
  BaseProductId text,
  BillToAccountId text,
  BillingFrequency text,
  BillingPreferenceId text,
  BillingRule text,
  ChargeType text,
  ClassificationHierarchyInfo text,
  ClassificationHierarchy text,
  ClassificationId text,
  CollaborationParentLineNumber text,
  CollaborationRequestId text,
  Comments text,
  CommitmentQuantity text,
  ConfigStatus text,
  ConfigurationId text,
  ConstraintCheckStatus text,
  ContractNumbers text,
  CopySourceBundleNumber text,
  CopySourceLineNumber text,
  CopySourceNumber text,
  Cost text,
  CouponCode text,
  Customizable int,
  DeltaPrice text,
  DeltaQuantity text,
  DerivedFromId text,
  Description text,
  EndDate text,
  ExtendedCost text,
  ExtendedDescription text,
  ExtendedPrice text,
  ExtendedQuantity text,
  FlatOptionPrice text,
  Frequency text,
  GroupAdjustmentPercent text,
  Guidance text,
  HasAttributes int,
  HasBaseProduct int,
  HasDefaults int,
  HasIncentives int,
  HasOptions int,
  HasTieredPrice int,
  HideCopyAction int,
  HideInvoiceDisplay int,
  IncentiveAdjustmentAmount text,
  IncentiveBasePrice text,
  IncentiveCode text,
  IncentiveExtendedPrice text,
  IncentiveId text,
  IncentiveType text,
  IsAssetPricing int,
  IsCustomPricing int,
  IsHidden int,
  IsOptionRollupLine int,
  IsOptional int,
  IsPrimaryLine int,
  IsPrimaryRampLine int,
  IsQuantityModifiable int,
  IsReadOnly int,
  IsSellingTermReadOnly int,
  IsUsageTierModifiable int,
  ItemSequence int,
  LineNumber int,
  LineSequence int,
  LineStatus text,
  LineType text,
  ListPrice text,
  LocationId text,
  MaxPrice text,
  MaxUsageQuantity text,
  MinMaxPriceAppliesTo text,
  MinPrice text,
  MinUsageQuantity text,
  NetAdjustmentPercent text,
  NetPrice text,
  NetUnitPrice text,
  OptionCost text,
  OptionGroupLabel text,
  OptionId text,
  OptionPrice text,
  OptionSequence int,
  ParentBundleNumber text,
  PaymentTermId text,
  PriceAdjustmentAmount text,
  PriceAdjustmentAppliesTo text,
  PriceAdjustmentType text,
  PriceAdjustment text,
  PriceGroup text,
  PriceIncludedInBundle int,
  PriceListId text,
  PriceListItemId text,
  PriceMethod text,
  PriceType text,
  TransferPriceLineItemId text,
  PriceUom text,
  PricingDate text,
  PricingGuidance text,
  PricingStatus text,
  PricingSteps text,
  PrimaryLineNumber int,
  ProductId text,
  ProductOptionId text,
  ProductVersion int,
  Quantity int,
  RelatedAdjustmentAmount text,
  RelatedAdjustmentAppliesTo text,
  RelatedAdjustmentType text,
  RelatedItemId text,
  RelatedPercentAppliesTo text,
  RelatedPercent text,
  RenewalAdjustmentAmount text,
  RenewalAdjustmentType text,
  RollupPriceMethod text,
  RollupPriceToBundle int,
  SellingFrequency text,
  SellingTerm int,
  ServiceLocationId text,
  ShipToAccountId text,
  StartDate text,
  StatusDetails text,
  SummaryGroupId text,
  SyncStatus text,
  TaxCodeId text,
  TaxInclusive int,
  Taxable int,
  Term int,
  TotalQuantity int,
  UnitCostAdjustment text,
  UnitPriceAdjustmentAuto text,
  UnitPriceAdjustmentManual text,
  Uom text,
  ExternalId text,
  RowVersion text,
  OwnerType text,
  ExternalLastUpdatedOn text,
  CurrencyId text,
  SellingUomId text,
  CPQ_calcfield int,
  CPQ_Colour text,
  CPQ_year text,
  CPQ_Color text,
  CPQ_vgpICK text,
  CPQ_newpl text,
  CPQ_VG1602 text,
  CPQ_Flavour text,
  CPQ_somefiled text,
  PCT_SoldTo text,
  PCT_ShipTo text,
  XOM_testAccount text,
  yuyw_Foquotetype text,
  snw_Reseller int,
  ApprovalStatus text,
  SJP_Multipicklist_01 text,
  SJP_MPL text,
  ShippingAddressId text,
  AVQA_CouponVoucher text,
  SCP_CashBack int,
  SCP_TestcashBack int,
  SCP_Tiny int,
  AVQA_TinyTots text,
  IsShippable text,
  SJP_TestPicklist_01 text,
  KSP_KSPricing text,
  TTT_TestNormalField text,
  ACCA_AUTO_Number_Int_01 int,
  ACCA_AUTO_Number_Dec_01 int,
  SCP_SVersion text,
  SJP_SJTestLanguages text,
  T11_dmx_customNetPrice int,
  T11_PCNoOfItemsAliasField int,
  TST_T11PCNoOfItemsAliasField001 int,
  T11_NRNewPrice int,
  MRP_TextInput text,
  SJP_testMoney int,
  MRP_Dimension1 text,
  MRP_Dimension2 text,
  MRP_Dimension3 text,
  SGP__DiscountCode text,
  VGP_ConfigurationNo int,
  VGP_ConfigurationMoney int,
  MRP_MR_Pricing_Currency int,
  PS_CustomLinePrice int,
  OrderLineItemId text,
  OrderLineStatus text,
  PK_CustomFieldAICPS text,
  PK_TestCust text,
  PK_AutoNum int,
  PK_LongString text,
  PK_PickLIst text,
  ACCA_TestPicklist_01 text,
  ATP_Automation_Color text,
  SGP__SG_IsReference text,
  SG2_IsReference2 text,
  VGP_GMCOLOR text,
  VGP_GMMutliPickList text,
  AQTP_Automation_Quoting_Color text,
  AQTP_Automation_Quote_String_CustomField text,
  AQTP_Automation_Quote_Integer_CustomField text,
  AQTP_Automation_Quote_Money_CustomField text,
  CancellationComments text,
  OrderMap text,
  SGP__CustomNumber text,
  VGP_IscopyEnabled text,
  BT_industry text,
  BT_function_dimension text,
  ACCA_AUTO_CheckBox_01 text,
  VGP_AccountVG text,
  VGP_AccountlocationVG text,
  MRP_AK_Text1 text,
  MRP_AK_Text2 text,
  MRP_AK_Text3 text,
  MRP_AK_Text4 text,
  MRP_AK_Text5 text,
  MRP_AK_Text6 text,
  SG2_SKTextAttr text,
  SG2_SKPicklist text,
  SG2_SKMultiPickList text,
  SG2_SKNumber text,
  MRP_AM_Field1 text,
  MRP_KP_Account text,
  MRP_AM_TextFieldName text,
  MRP_AM_PickListField text,
  dc_Customer_Rating text,
  dc_Annual_Uplift text,
  dc_Usage_Quantity text,
  PS_MinimumFee text,
  SJP_SJTestPicklist_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestCheckBox_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestMultiPicklist_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestDate_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestMoney_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestNumber_Dec_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestNumber_Int_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestDateTime_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestString_01 text,
  SJP_SJTestMPL text,
  SJP_SJTestPicklist_02 text,
  SJP_SJTest_Country text,
  SJP_SJTest_Locales text,
  SJP_SJTest_GlobalPick_01 text,
  SJP_SJTest_a_A_001 text,
  SGP__SRK_SLA text,
  SGP__SRK_SLA_PL text,
  SPP_SPTestPicklist_01 text,
  SPP_SPTestPicklist11 text,
  SPP_SPTestPicklist12 text,
  MTP_LIQuantity int,
  NKP_GCPQ12178_Reference_Location text,
  SPP_NewPrice text,
  SPP_DealColor text,
  PP2_Automation_Pricing_Decimal_1596635363104 text,
  PP2_Automation_Pricing_Money_1596643488253 text,
  PP2_Automation_Pricing_String_1596643557143 text,
  PRIMARY KEY (QuoteId, Id)
);
```

Comment: Not that this is going to help you, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316137/what-are-the-maximum-number-of-columns-allowed-in-cassandra

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the Max table schema size. The maximum size of a table schema is  350 KB.

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/quotas.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a quota defined in Amazon keyspaces (for Apache Cassandra). Max row size by default is 1MB. You can refer the quotas here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/quotas.html. I think you need to update max row size value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. the row im trying to insert is less than 8KB so i not sure size is an issue here